# Bootstrap Custom themes Using MVC Razor

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I m developing a web application using ASP.NET MVC with Razor. This web application will launch different dynamic products with different color themes.
I need to change the color of following in bootstrap:

- Navbar
- Nav pills
- Buttons

solutions I have found:

- Kickstrap have different color themes
- I can launch different bootstrap CSS for different products (will customized these bootstrap themes from their website)

Is there any better/optimized way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I generally override bootstrap styles by writing my own css classes.  For example, if I wanted to override the nav-pills I would do something similar to this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-pills-custom">
    ...
</ul>
```

** Note: You still need to add the nav-pills class along with your custom css class.

If you are using less, I generally create a new less file and add my styles there.  Otherwise you can add the styles to your css file.

```
.nav-pills-custom {
    ** Override bootstrap settings here (such as color)
    ** Note: You may need to add !important
}
```

You can do something similar for the navbar and buttons.